# Why the negative reshape (-1) in MNIST tutorial?

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

Reading [the Tensorflow MNIST tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/mnist/pros/), I stumbled over the line

```
x_image = tf.reshape(x, [-1,28,28,1])
```

`28, 28` comes from `width, height`, `1` comes from the number of channels. But why `-1`?

I guess this is related to mini-batch training, but I wondered why `-1` and not `1` (which seems to give the same result in numpy).
(Probably related: Why does the reshape of numpy give the same results for `-1`,`-2` and `1`)?

Comment: Have you had a look at np.reshape() docs ? See the description of newshape: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`-1` means that the length in that dimension is inferred. This is done based on the constraint that the number of elements in an `ndarray` or `Tensor` when reshaped must remain the same. In the tutorial, each image is a row vector (784 elements) and there are lots of such rows (let it be `n`, so there are `784n` elements). So, when you write

`x_image = tf.reshape(x, [-1, 28, 28, 1])`

TensorFlow can infer that `-1` is `n`.

Comment: thanks, that makes sense. I just found the docs https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/array_ops/shapes_and_shaping#reshape

Answer (score 5):

In the MNIST tutorial that you are reading, the desired shape for your input layer : [batch_size, 28, 28, 1]

x_image = tf.reshape(x, [-1,28,28,1])

Here -1 for input x specifies that this dimension should be dynamically computed based on the number of input values in x, holding the size of all other dimensions constant. This allows us to treat batch_size(parameter with value -1) as a hyperparameter that we can tune.

Comment: What does your answer contribute in comparison to Priyathams answer?

Answer (score -1):

−1 indicates that the length on the current axis needs to be automatically deduced according to the rule that the total elements of the tensor remain unchanged